# How to design the relations for a mall project?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata

[The relation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgKzK.jpg)

I have three tables `goods`、`category` and `brand`, the category has many goods,the brand also has many goods.I have two cases below:

1、The relation between goods and category is "manyToOne",defined the relation between goods and brad is also "manyToOne"(It means you should define "manyToOne twice in the goods yml mapping");

2、Defined the relation between goods and category is "manyToOne",defined the relation between brand and category is "manyToMany".

The case one which I tried is not successful,because u cant't denfine  "manyToOne" twice in one yml mapping;The case two I haven't try yet,I thought it's very redundant;

How can I find a mature solution,I'm trying to find some details on Sylius which is the open-source about the mall project.  I have been puzzled in a few days.

Comment: from what i understand you need to build relationship between `brand` and `goods` right?

Comment: yes,use the command with  symfony2

Comment: What exactly does "is failed" mean?

Comment: I update the pro ,it's very clear

Comment: @liam where is the error? I don't understand the image you provide. Anyway, with this configuration it should work well. Did you build methods in each entity to get related objects?

Comment: @Muriano   I update my pro again, I thought the code is right, maybe my thinking is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have "manyToOne" twice in your Goods YAML mapping...

Comment: I updated my pro, thank u to remain me about how to give a good answer for the kind people , I'm trying my best to describe my pro, could you give me some idea?